# Limit on a triple integral

Tags: integration

> > The region $R$ in the first octant bounded by the coordinate planes and the planes $x + z = 1$ and $y +2z = 2$.

I know that the triple integral over the region $R$ is  $${\int \int\limits_R \int} 1 \; dy \; dz \; dx = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{1-x} \int\limits_{0}^{2 - 2z} 1 \;  dy \;  dz \; dx.$$ I want to change the order of integration, what are the limit of $x, y$ and  $z$, if I choose the order of the triple integration 
$${\int \int\limits_R \int} 1 \; dz \; dx \; dy.$$

Comment: This becomes two integrals over two triangles in the $xy$ plane, separated by the line $y=2x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "top" of this region is piecewise continuous in terms of $z$, with a split along the plane $y=2x$. So the integral becomes

$$\int_0^2 \int_{\frac{y}{2}}^1 \int_0^{1-x} dz dx dy + \int_0^2 \int_0^{\frac{y}{2}} \int_0^{1-\frac{y}{2}} dz dx dy$$